# Selenium webdriver for chrome too slow

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working on a video consultation application where I need three separate windows to remain open simultaneously for a test case.

I am using keyword driven framework using java with selenium and following code to open up new instances of chrome every time:

```
public static void OPEN_BROWSER(String object,String data){     
    Log.info("OPENS NEW BROWSER");
    try{                
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",     "C:/chromedriver.exe"); 

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

            options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");

            options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

            driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

             Log.info("Chrome browser started");
             System.out.println("Chrome browser started");
        }catch (Exception e){
        Log.info("Not able to open the Browser --- " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Not able to open the Browser --- " + e.getMessage());
        DriverScript.bResult = false;
    }

public static void GOTO_URL(String object, String data){
    try{
        Log.info("Navigating to URL");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(data);
        //driver.navigate().to(data);
        Log.info("Chrome browser started");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.info("Not able to navigate --- " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Not able to navigate --- " + e.getMessage());
        DriverScript.bResult = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is every time I am trying to call GOTO_URL function, since a new webdriver is launched from OPEN_BROWSER function , it takes more than 5 minutes to load a URL and even more in some cases.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have checked opening url manually?

Comment: yes, manually its working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179808/chromedriver-is-extremely-slow-on-a-specific-machine-using-selenium-grid-and-ne

Turn off automatic proxy detection:

```
chromeOptions.Proxy = null; // Or similar
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer, but it didn't explain everything. Didn't know that I need to create a ChromeOptions object then change the proxy to null.  Here is my code that solved the problem:

```
        string driverPath = @"C:\where ever the driver it\";
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.Proxy = null;
        IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(driverPath, chromeOptions);
```